# String is not Convertible to DictionaryIndex<String, Any>

Tags: dictionary, swift

I'm working with dictionaries in Swift which need to hold differing types of value, although the keys are pretty much all strings. This was painfully easy with Objective-C, but Swift's generally very useful type safety seems to make this more difficult.

I had been working with [String: AnyObject] dictionaries until I ran into being unable to downcast a resulting AnyObject to a Swift string, which technically isn't an object but a value type. I can make peace with this as it seems to make sense, although if there's a way around it (besides reverting to NSString objects which I don't want to do), i'd like to know it.

The logical solution to the above seems to be switching to use `[String: Any]` dictionaries, but in doing so I'm finding a problem even with a basic piece of code:

```
func abc() {
    var dict : [String: Any] = [String: Any]()
    if dict["success"] != nil {
       ...
    }
}
```

The 3rd line of code above gives the error:

> 'String' is not convertible to 'DictionaryIndex<String, Any>'.

Now I seem to have a dictionary that contains types that I suspect I can downcast as I need to, but that no longer seems accessible by its keys, which as far as I can see are of exactly the right type (indeed, although it's a literal, even the error suggests I am passing a String). What am I missing, given all I'm actually trying to achieve is dictionaries with easily accessible values of multiple types which I can actually retrieve in a var/let of the correct Swift type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here seems to be your use of `Any`. `Dictionary` has two subscript methods:

```
subscript (i: DictionaryIndex<Key, Value>) -> (Key, Value) { get }
subscript (key: Key) -> Value?
```

The compiler incorrectly assumes you want the first one, and then complains that the `String` you passed in can't be converted to `DictionaryIndex<Key, Value>`.

To avoid this problem, you can either:

- Force it to use a specific subscript accessor: `if dict["success"] as Any? != nil ...`
- Declare your dictionary as `[String:AnyObject]` instead — since tuples aren't objects. From [the guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-XID_498),

  > - `AnyObject` can represent an instance of any class type.
  > - `Any` can represent an instance of any type at all, apart from function types.

If you believe this is an error, you may wish to [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Great answer, thanks, and the cast to Any? seems to achieve what I want. I'm not sure whether it assuming the first accessor is an error or not as I don't really understand its intended usage. I need to have another read of the guide I think. Thanks again!

Comment: But how does this work when you have multiple levels of nested dictionary?  I m getting the same error, but my line looks more like:  dict["bug"]["spotted"]["red"]++  (the innermost dict is String:Int, the rest are all String:Any.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I guess I am asking where would I insert the 'as Any?' in my line of code: bugs["ladybug"]as Any?["spotted"]as Any?["red"]As Int?++  That doesn't seem to work for me :(

Comment: Yes, when supplying an object that satisfies one out of two function declarations and the compiler picks the one that can't be satisfied, that is definitely a bug.
Has anybody filed it yet? If so, please post the radar number. If not, I'll get on it when I have the time.