# AnyObject (from JSONObjectWithData) is not convertible to [String : Any]

Tags: json, dictionary, swift

I moved from using a [String : AnyObject] dictionary to using a [String : Any] in the hope of being able to take advantage of native Swift value types (e.g String) in the dictionary values rather than old foundation ones (e.g. NSString). This seems to have worked almost everywhere, however at the very source of what i'm trying to achieve is this line of code:

```
let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)
```

In Swift this returns an `AnyObject!`, which looks exactly as expected when i use println to show it in the console, and the long signature in the debug area suggests an NSDictionary underlies it, however when I try to cast this with `as [String : Any]` at the end of the above line I get the following error:

`AnyObject is not convertible to [String : Any]`

Why would this happen, and how can I fix it, bearing in mind I do want to use [String : Any] here, and can't see any good reason it shouldn't be possible, and a good solution.

Comment: Note that `String` is not an object, it is a struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After experimenting a bit in Playground, the code below seems to work. Note that `Any` does not work, while `AnyObject` seems to work as expected.

```
let jsonString = "{\"name\":\"John\", \"age\":23}"
let jsonData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, 
   options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as [String:AnyObject]
// ["name": "John", "age": __NSCFNumber]
let name = json["name"] as AnyObject! as String  // "John"
let age  = json["age"]  as AnyObject! as Int     // 23
```

Comment: I think it will work, but for `[String: AnyObject]`. As I said, I'm  specifically seeking a way to work with `[String: Any]`, because if I use `[String: AnyObject]`, I end up with values that can't be cast to Swift types in other parts of my code, the only solution being  give up on Swift types and cast things to `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSBoolean` etc. I'm trying to live as much in Swift as possible, but it doesn't seem to make it easy. The earlier part of this discussion was [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272862/string-is-not-convertible-to-dictionaryindexstring-any)

Comment: I apologise - I was very quick to dismiss your answer. Although it doesn't give me a solution to using Any, it does provide a solution to the AnyObject issue from the previous question, in the form of that double casting you're doing at the end.If i'm reading it right, the point would be that the main json object is implicitly unwrapped , but the elements within are not, meaning I was previously trying to cast an Optional to a String. The syntax required here seems a bit clunky, but it does work, so thanks!

Comment: This fixes the problem for me, but the syntax seems so weird.

Comment: @Mundi If I don't know the key: "age" map the value's type, the value maybe `Int`, maybe `String`, maybe other type, how can I get the `value`?