# AnyObject to Array?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, type-conversion

I'm using `NSJSONSerialization` as so:

```
let twData: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: &dataError)
```

This gives me an `AnyObject?`.

From here, I want to convert it to `Array<Dictionary<String,String>>`

I've tried all sorts, leading up to this:

```
var twDataArray: Array<Dictionary<String,String>>? = twData? as? Array<Dictionary<String,String>>
```

which simply gives the error:

> Type 'Array>' does not conform to protocol
>   'AnyObject'.

And putting the simpler version:

```
var twDataArray = twData as Array
```

gives the error:

> Cannot convert the expression's type 'AnyObject?' to type 'Array'

Comment: possible duplicate of [AnyObject (from JSONObjectWithData) is not convertible to \[String : Any\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25349735/anyobject-from-jsonobjectwithdata-is-not-convertible-to-string-any)

Answer (score 31):

To cast your data to an array:

```
var twDataArray = (twData as! NSArray) as Array
```

The code above first casts `twData` to an `NSArray`, and then to an `Array` via a **bridging cast**. A bridging cast is a special type of cast which converts an Objective-C type to it's [`_ObjectiveCBridgeable`](http://nshint.io/blog/2015/10/07/easy-cast-with-_ObjectiveCBridgeable/) conformant, Swift counterpart.

(Note that I didn't need to write `Array<AnyObject>` because the element `AnyObject` is inferred in the bridging cast from `NSArray` → `Array`)

Note that the cast above is a **forced downcast**. Only use this if you're absolutely sure that `twData` is going to be an instance of `NSArray`. Otherwise, use an optional cast.

```
var twDataArray = (twData as? NSArray) as Array?
```

Comment: how can i cast it to specific type like [UInt8]

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, you can iterate through the array as given below.

```
for element in twData as! Array<AnyObject> {
    print(element)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in a playground:

```
var data: Array<Dictionary<String,String>>? = twData as? Array<Dictionary<String, String>>
```

the difference from your code is that `twData` does not require the `?` at the end - it is an optional so the `as?` operator will take care of verifying that it can be case to an array of dictionaries - needless to say, if it's nil, `as?` will evaluate to nil

Answer (score 0):

```
let twData: Any = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: &dataError)
```

Do not use `AnyObject`. Use `Any` instead of `AnyObject`. It will work fine. `AnyObject` is for all reference type and Array is a value type. That's why this comes. Change it to `Any`.

Answer (score -1):

As you already know it is a String type you are inserting to something transformable, please do:

```
if let twoDataArray = twData as? Array<Dictionary<String, String>>{
   for data in twoDataArray{
       print(data)
   }
}
```

This will guard you from a crashing app when the dictionary is not of type `<String,String>`.