# Using Objective C/C in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm having problems using an objective c/c library in swift.

```
    for i in results {
        print(i.interface.index)
    }
```

When I try to access the property 'interface' of the object, I get this error from Swift:

Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member interface.

But 'i' is a MidiBusInterface object as I can check here:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpuXO.png)

```
@interface MidiBusInterface : NSObject
{
    @public
    MIDIBUS_INTERFACE* interface;
}

typedef struct midibus_interface
{
   uint8_t index;

   eMidiBusInterfaceType type;

   eMidiBusInterfaceMode mode;

   uint8_t transport;

   char* ident;

   bool_t enabled;

   bool_t network_connections;

   uint64_t event_count;  

   uint64_t transport_delay_average_mt;

   uint64_t transport_delay_average_deviation_mt;

   bool_t clock_running;                // clock is running
   uint64_t start_tick_count;           // total number of ticks since start
   uint64_t cont_tick_count;            // ticks since continue (or start)
   float current_bpm;                   // current bpm measured
   float  min_bpm, max_bpm, avg_bpm;    // min/max/avg bpm this clock run
   float bpm_average_deviation_percent; // bpm standard deviation %

   bool_t present;                           // interface present
   uint64_t tick_anchor_mt;                  // timestamp of start/cont event
   uint64_t last_tick_timestamp_received_mt; // timestamp of last tick
   bool_t is_owner;                          // set to true if app owns        interface
} MIDIBUS_INTERFACE;
```

Any clue?

Big thanks!

Comment: Please show the declaration of `MIDIBUS_INTERFACE`? Is it a C type?

Comment: Yes, it is. I will update the question with the declaration

Answer (score 0):

Is results an Objective C collection? You would need to cast results as type of MidiBusInterface eg:

```
for i in results as? [MidiBusInterface] {
        print(i.interface.index)
    }
```

Comment: Typecasting gives me this -> Cannot convert value of type '[AnyObject]' to type '[MidiBusInterface]'

Comment: Check if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097982/anyobject-to-array

Comment: It allows me to make the conversion from NSArray to Array, but I still cannot access the object properties, and now I cannot see any property of i in the debugger

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at the print statement, does it hit that line?

Comment: yes, i object looks so -> i MidiBusInterface 0x79ef5ae0 0x79ef5ae0
NSObject NSObject  
isa MidiBusInterface * 0x79ef5ae0 0x79ef5ae0

Answer (score 0):

How about a slightly more verbose, but easier to analyze:

```
for i in results {
    if let midibus = i as! MidiBusInterface {
        if let iface = midibus.interface {
            print(iface.index)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: casting in second line is not working, as anyobject is not convertible to MidiBusInterface

Comment: @AlexVazquez try the forced cast 'as!' instead.  Swift now requires this for a cast that can fail.

Comment: with as! -> Initializer for conditional binding must have optional value. If I remove the first conditional binding, I get 'Value of type 'MidiBusInterface' has no member 'interface' - when it do have, and so I can check in the debugger